# Why are unbound implicits invalid when in function position?

Tags: idris, implicit-typing

In *Type-Driven Development with Idris* ch 3, Brady says

> Idris will not treat *every* undefined name as an unbound implicit - only names that begin with a lowercase letter and that appear either on their own or in a function argument. Given the following,
>
> `test: f m a -> b -> a`
>
> ... `f` isn't treated as an unbound implicit, meaning that it *must* be defined elsewhere for this type to be valid.

Why can't Idris infer `f` just as it infers the types of the other variables?